# what is the advantage of block file write

Tags: linux, performance, io

i want to know what is the advantage of writing file block by block.i can think it will reduce the io operation. but in linux like environment  data anyway goes to the page cache and background daemon doing the physical disk writing(correct me if i'm wrong).In that kind of environment what are the advantages of block writing?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about the advantages of using larger blocks, rather than writing character-by-character.

You have to consider that each use of a system call (e.g. [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write)) has a minimum cost by itself, regardless of *what* is being done. In addition it may cause the calling process to be subjected to a [context switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), which has a cost of its own and also allows other processes to use the CPU, causing even more significant delays.

Therefore - even if we forget about direct and synchronous I/O modes where each operation may make it to the disk immediately - it makes sense from a performance standpoint to reduce the impact of those constant costs by moving around larger blocks of data.

A simple demonstration using `dd` to transfer 1,000,000 bytes:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test.txt count=1000000 bs=1 # 1,000,000 blocks of 1 byte
1000000+0 records in
1000000+0 records out
1000000 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 1.55779 s, 642 kB/s
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test.txt count=100000 bs=10 # 100,000 blocks of 10 bytes
100000+0 records in
100000+0 records out
1000000 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.172038 s, 5.8 MB/s
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test.txt count=10000 bs=100 # 10,000 blocks of 100 bytes
10000+0 records in
10000+0 records out
1000000 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.0262843 s, 38.0 MB/s
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test.txt count=1000 bs=1000 # 1,000 blocks of 1,000 bytes
1000+0 records in
1000+0 records out
1000000 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.0253754 s, 39.4 MB/s
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test.txt count=100 bs=10000 # 100 blocks of 10,000 bytes
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
1000000 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.00919108 s, 109 MB/s
```

As an additional benefit, using larger-blocks of data lets both the I/O scheduler and the allocator of the filesystem to make more accurate estimates about your actual workload.